# User session tracking using Spring boot as server with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, session-variables

Can someone tell me how should I implement session tracking for a user after I login in the application?

I think the steps are:

Login -> store username as session values -> use this value in other angularjs controllers and I need to store the user session in the database

The session should end when the user is inactive for 1 minute or he leaves the page

I read something about `SessionAtributes`  and store the session variable using the `ModelMap` but I don't know how to receive those variables in angular controllers